# .net mvc and manos what's different?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-applications, manos

i have interest in asp.net web app use html5 websocket, long polling.

i've heard that for use websock, longpoll must need socket listening server process separately iis web server.

i thought that node.js, tornado, misultin and etc... are having special factor for async communication but they are just web server program.

.net has [manos](https://github.com/jacksonh/manos) project, but i looked document, it is just framework same as mvc framework.

my question is, i want to make lightweight webapp. then what do I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need something lightweight and you want code using a .NET language, I suggest you Manos.

If language is not a problem and you're good in Javascript, node.js as a lot of npm modules to help you accomplish a lot of tasks.

Please read this blog article: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.it/2010/12/explosion-of-alternative-web-frameworks.html

Regards,
Giacomo